# I am trying to create filters and when i click on the button to filter the elements it does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter

I am trying to create filters in an HTML webpage using HTML, CSS, and javascript.  When I click on the button to filter the elements it doesn't work. Although it changes color. You can test out the code and see for yourself. If you can help me that would be incredibly nice of you. I have also got some of the code from the w3schools website.

I don't think that anything is wrong with the HTML code since I have reviewed it carefully but I'm not 100 percent sure.

↓HTML↓

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Web Player</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="filters">
        <button id="all" class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> All Genres</button>
        <button id="rap" class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('rap')"> Rap</button>
        <button id="pop" class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('pop')"> Pop</button>
        <button id="other" class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('other')"> Other</button>
    </div>
    <header class="title" id="webplayertitle">
        GMusic WebPlayer
    </header>

    <div>
        <h2 id="tohi">Top-Hits</h2>
        <hr id="line">
        <div class="filtercontainer boxes">
            <div class="filterDiv rap">Lucid Dreams</div>
            <div class="filterDiv pop">Havana</div>
            <div class="filterDiv rap">Rap God</div>
            <div class="filterDiv pop">Senorita</div>
            <div class="filterDiv rap">River</div>
            <div class="filterDiv pop">Thank You, Next</div>
            <div class="filterDiv rap pop">Old Town Road</div>
            <div class="filterDiv other">Bad Guy</div>
            <div class="filterDiv pop">Sucker</div>
            <div class="filterDiv pop">Sunflower</div>
            <div class="filterDiv other">7 Rings</div>
            <div class="filterDiv rap pop">Gods plan</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

↓Important parts of the CSS↓

```
div.boxes {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  top: 175px;
  left: 50px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

div.boxes div {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: #202020;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.btn {
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  color: #202020;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 14px 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-color: lightsalmon;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  color: white;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.filters {
  text-align: center;
}

#all {
  margin-right: 250px;
}

#rap {
  margin-right: 250px;
}

#pop {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
```

↓Important parts of the javascript↓

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    removeClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) addClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function addClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function removeClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

var btnContainer = document.getElementById("filters");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Comment: The code you have properly adds the `show` class to the divs. All you're missing is CSS rules that hide the divs by default and display them when they have the `show` class: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/moe51yvu/ (also note that some of your code is outdated, for instance adding and removing classes is natively supported now, and also [don't use w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com), please)

Comment: Can you use ES6?

Comment: If you add the CSS rule .filterDiv:not(.show){ display: none;} it should work. Your question wasn't very specific, though, it was more like "look at my code and tell me what's wrong". I encourage you to rewrite your code after reading up on document.querySelector, array functions and Element.classList. MDN is there for you.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks so much for the help. I am 11 years old and this is my first StackOverflow post. I appreciate you helping me and am sure to not use w3schools again. Thanks!